# Evenly Distributed Slice of Django QuerySet (or Python list)

Tags: python, django, slice

I'd like to get some values from a database and slice "n" of them, say to draw on a graph.

I'm starting with a Django QuerySet, but I don't think this is something I can reduce just via the ORM, so I'm fine with getting a list of values and then using whatever libs in Python are available to get a sample of the data.

So if I have a dataset of a thousand items, I'd like to be able to grab an evenly distributed range of non-random samples from that dataset, always including the start and end points and then evenly distributing the elements in between.

For instance, if:

```
data = [x for x in xrange(0, 777)]
```

and I wanted ten of them, how would I get a list back not of every 10th item, but exactly ten list items distributed evenly over the total number of elements in the list?

I'm trying:

```
number_of_results = 10
step = len(data) / number_of_results
data[::step]
```

But I'm hoping there's a more efficient way (and also a way that keeps the end point and returns exactly number_of_results items, even if the step between the items can't be exactly even).

Answer (score 1):

There might be more efficient ways of doing it, but this is just a thought:

```
qs_ids = list(ModelA.objects.order_by('id').values_list('id', flat=True))

number_of_results = 10
step = len(qs_ids) / number_of_results
ids = data[::step]

qs = ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=ids).order_by('id')
```